# how to get the id of last affected rows in php mysqldatabase?

Tags: php, mysql

My code

```
$query = "select * from others";
```

But it takes previous id . when I insert the first row , it takes the id value will be 0 , then again insert the second row, it takes the id value will be 1.

Comment: $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($query);

Comment: Which driver are you using PDO, MYSQLI ?

Comment: mysqli @SaadSuri

Comment: Then use @AnandChoudhary comment as a solution

Comment: You're not making a whole lot of sense

Answer (score 6):

**Please Use my simple code it will be helpful for you**

```
$selectquery="SELECT id FROM tableName ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($selectquery);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['id'];
```